# May women have short hair?

Tags: women, hair

May women wear their hair short or must they have long hair?  May they have fringes?

Answer (score 3):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

> Imam Bukhari narrated from Ibn Abbas that the **Prophet (Sallallahu
>   Alaihi wa Sallam) "Has cursed men who make themselves like women and
>   has cursed women who make themselves like men"**

So, as long as you are not falling in this category, it is fine to cut your hair.

> It was narrated **in Saheeh Muslim “The wives of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) used to cut their hair until it came just below their ears.”**
>   (al-Hayd, 320)

**Al-Nawawi said:** this indicates that it is permissible for women to cut their hair short.

But keep in mind first hadees and also **not to intimate kuffar or immoral women**, as it is also prohibited, and you are good to go.

Also, Shaykh Ibn Baaz (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:

> *We do not know anything (to disallow) cutting women’s hair. What is
>   forbidden is shaving it. You should not shave your hair but you may
>   cut it and reduce its length or volume; we know of nothing wrong with
>   that. But that should be done in a proper manner which will please you
>   and your husband. You should come to some agreement with him on a kind
>   of haircut that does not resemble kaafir women, because if you leave
>   it long, it will be a lot of trouble to wash it and comb it. So if the
>   hair is very long or thick, and the woman cuts it to reduce its length
>   or volume, that doesn’t matter. Cutting some of it will make it more
>   beautiful, which will please both the woman and her husband. So we do
>   not know of any reason to disallow that. But shaving it altogether is
>   not permissible, except in the case of sickness. And Allaah is the
>   Source of strength.*
>
> See Fataawa al-Mar’ah al-Muslimah, part 2, p. 515

For more details you can read [Women cutting their hair and removing facial hair](https://islamqa.info/en/13744)

### Allah knows best